# OpenLayers not showing second map when rendering two maps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gis, openlayers

I am using Openlayers to create maps in a Vite React Typescript project. I am creating two maps and setting them to div elements like this:

```
const mapRef1 = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
const mapRef2 = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

useEffect(()=>{
 
  if(!mapRef1.current) return
  const map1 = new Map({
     target: mapRef1.current
  )}

  if(!mapRef2.current) return
  const map2 = new Map({
     target: mapRef2.current
  )}
},[])

return (
  <div style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}>
    <div ref = {mapRef1} style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}></div>
    <div ref = {mapRef2} style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}></div>
  </div>
)
```

However, while both maps seem to appear on the screen, only one of them shows the actual map and one is just blank.

I am using Openlayers 7.4, React 18.2, Tailwind 3.3.2.

I have tried to set the target as plain text string, like target: "map1" and set the  but not help.

Comment: It looks like a copy-paste error. Update your checks to the actual refs mapRef1 and mapRef2. In the if check you are checking for a non existing ref. And also consider giving some height and width to the div's

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Setting the correct refs and also adding height width does not solve it. It seems like the maps loose "focus" or something so that they disappear. Or that when I create the first map, it appears, but as the second is created it removes the first map. But even with the "correct use" of the mapRef it still isn't working as I would expect

Comment: Please update the code in the question to your latest state and then i will continue to solve your issue.

Comment: One at a Time: Try initializing only one map at a time. Comment out the initialization for the second map and see if the first one renders correctly. Then do the opposite: comment out the first and initialize only the second. This can help isolate if the issue is tied to one specific map instance or if there is genuine interference happening between them.

Answer (score 1):

Fix 1: Consider giving a fixed height and width to both individually, width and height 100%, can have a different layout considering the HTML they are encapsulated in.

```
<div ref={mapRef1} className="w-full h-64"></div>
<div ref={mapRef2} className="w-full h-64"></div>
```

Fix 2: Consider adding a view to both of them you can also have different views for them, which you can create using OSM,XYZ or any other class.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!mapRef1.current || !mapRef2.current) return;

  const view = new View({
    center: [0, 0], // Longitude, Latitude
    zoom: 2
  });

  const osmLayer = new TileLayer({ source: new OSM() });

  const map1 = new Map({
    target: mapRef1.current,
    layers: [osmLayer],
    view: view
  });

  const map2 = new Map({
    target: mapRef2.current,
    layers: [osmLayer],
    view: view.clone()  // Clone the view so each map has its own instance
  });
}, []);
```

FIX 3: **Update Map Size**: After creating the map, you might need to force the map to update its size. Sometimes, the map doesn't correctly render the first time due to the container size not being determined yet or other rendering delays.

Run this effect after the useEffect with [] dependency array has run

```
map1.updateSize();
map2.updateSize();
```

Let me know which one works, in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough response. Neither of this fixes work, but from my understanding of Openlayers this should all do the trick! I found a solution that worked, yet I am not fully getting why it works and not the other. I have now created a function in a separate .ts file that creates a map, and I take as input the id of a div. 

const map = createOLMap("targetDivId")

when I do this inside the useEffect instead of creating the maps individually, it somehow works.

Comment: Mention this in the Question itself as a P.S. EDIT note. So this is helpful to someone who faces the same issue. Happy Coding.